# Bitbake server does not start

Tags: yocto, bitbake, network-drive

I am having some trouble with building the Yocto project, hope I can find some help. Is there any way to fix the following issue? Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks.

## My goal

I am building the default image from this guide : https://docs.yoctoproject.org/brief-yoctoprojectqs/index.html
This build takes up a lot of space, so I want to build it on a network drive.

## Current situation

I am able to finish the build normally if I am using a normal folder.
If I use the the shared drive that is mounted in the system, the build never starts. The error looks like this :

```
$ bitbake core-image-sato
NOTE: Bitbake server didn't start within 5 seconds, waiting for 90
ERROR: Error parsing configuration files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/NetworkShare/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/persist_data.py", line 45, in SQLTable.wrap_func(*args=('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BB_URI_HEADREVS(key TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, value TEXT);',), **kwargs={}):
                         if self.connection is None and reconnect:
    >                        self.reconnect()
     
  File "/mnt/NetworkShare/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/persist_data.py", line 105, in SQLTable.reconnect():
             self.connection.text_factory = str
    >        self._setup_database()
     
  File "/mnt/NetworkShare/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/persist_data.py", line 50, in SQLTable.wrap_func(*args=(), **kwargs={}):
                             try:
    >                            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
                             except sqlite3.OperationalError as exc:
  File "/mnt/NetworkShare/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/persist_data.py", line 79, in SQLTable.wrap_func(*args=(), **kwargs={}):
                         with contextlib.closing(self.connection.cursor()) as cursor:
    >                        return f(self, cursor, *args, **kwargs)
                 return wrap_func
  File "/mnt/NetworkShare/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/persist_data.py", line 93, in SQLTable._setup_database(cursor=<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f3d59c5dab0>):
         def _setup_database(self, cursor):
    >        cursor.execute("pragma synchronous = off;")
             # Enable WAL and keep the autocheckpoint length small (the default is
sqlite3.OperationalError: disk I/O error
```

## Details

The /etc/fstab line to mount the drive is :

```
NetworkShare /mnt/NetworkShare 9p trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L,_netdev,rw 0 0
```

The host is Ubuntu server 20.04 running in a VM inside UnRAID. I don't think the VM is  the issue (It's possible that I am very wrong) because I get the same error if I mount an external share on my own computer (OpenSuse Tumbleweed) and try to build in it.

The bitbake-cookerdaemon.log :

```
1221 13:38:18.293775 --- Starting bitbake server pid 1221 at 2022-01-19 13:38:18.293689 ---
1221 13:38:18.333537 Started bitbake server pid 1221
1221 13:38:18.339125 Entering server connection loop
1221 13:38:18.340399 Accepting [<socket.socket fd=6, family=AddressFamily.AF_UNIX, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=bitbake.sock>] ([])
1221 13:38:18.341382 Processing Client
1221 13:38:18.342099 Connecting Client
1221 13:38:18.343689 Running command ['setFeatures', [2]]
1221 13:38:18.344805 Command Completed
1221 13:38:18.346085 Running command ['updateConfig', {'abort': True, 'force': False, 'invalidate_stamp': None, 'dry_run': False, 'dump_signatures': [], 'extra_assume_provided': [], 'profile': False, 'prefile': [], 'postfile': [], 'server_timeout': None, 'nosetscene': False, 'setsceneonly': False, 'skipsetscene': False, 'runall': None, 'runonly': None, 'writeeventlog': None, 'build_verbose_shell': False, 'build_verbose_stdout': False, 'default_loglevel': 20, 'debug_domains': {}}, {'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'PWD': '/mnt/NetworkShare/yocto/poky/build', 'LOGNAME': 'metics', 'HOME': '/home/metics', 'BBPATH': '/mnt/NetworkShare/yocto/poky/build', 'BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE': 'ALL_PROXY BBPATH_EXTRA BB_LOGCONFIG BB_NO_NETWORK BB_NUMBER_THREADS BB_SETSCENE_ENFORCE BB_SRCREV_POLICY DISTRO FTPS_PROXY FTP_PROXY GIT_PROXY_COMMAND HTTPS_PROXY HTTP_PROXY MACHINE NO_PROXY PARALLEL_MAKE SCREENDIR SDKMACHINE SOCKS5_PASSWD SOCKS5_USER SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_AUTH_SOCK STAMPS_DIR TCLIBC TCMODE all_proxy ftp_proxy ftps_proxy http_proxy https_proxy no_proxy ', 'USER': 'metics', 'PATH': '/mnt/NetworkShare/yocto/poky/scripts:/mnt/NetworkShare/yocto/poky/bitbake/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin', 'LC_ALL': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'TERMCAP': 'SC|screen.xterm-256color|VT 100/ANSI X3.64 virtual terminal:DO=\\E[%dB:LE=\\E[%dD:RI=\\E[%dC:UP=\\E[%dA:bs:bt=\\E[Z:cd=\\E[J:ce=\\E[K:cl=\\E[H\\E[J:cm=\\E[%i%d;%dH:ct=\\E[3g:do=^J:nd=\\E[C:pt:rc=\\E8:rs=\\Ec:sc=\\E7:st=\\EH:up=\\EM:le=^H:bl=^G:cr=^M:it#8:ho=\\E[H:nw=\\EE:ta=^I:is=\\E)0:li#51:co#110:am:xn:xv:LP:sr=\\EM:al=\\E[L:AL=\\E[%dL:cs=\\E[%i%d;%dr:dl=\\E[M:DL=\\E[%dM:dc=\\E[P:DC=\\E[%dP:im=\\E[4h:ei=\\E[4l:mi:IC=\\E[%d@:ks=\\E[?1h\\E=:ke=\\E[?1l\\E>:vi=\\E[?25l:ve=\\E[34h\\E[?25h:vs=\\E[34l:ti=\\E[?1049h:te=\\E[?1049l:us=\\E[4m:ue=\\E[24m:so=\\E[3m:se=\\E[23m:mb=\\E[5m:md=\\E[1m:mh=\\E[2m:mr=\\E[7m:me=\\E[m:ms:Co#8:pa#64:AF=\\E[3%dm:AB=\\E[4%dm:op=\\E[39;49m:AX:vb=\\Eg:G0:as=\\E(0:ae=\\E(B:ac=\\140\\140aaffggjjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~..--++,,hhII00:po=\\E[5i:pf=\\E[4i:Km=\\E[M:k0=\\E[10~:k1=\\EOP:k2=\\EOQ:k3=\\EOR:k4=\\EOS:k5=\\E[15~:k6=\\E[17~:k7=\\E[18~:k8=\\E[19~:k9=\\E[20~:k;=\\E[21~:F1=\\E[23~:F2=\\E[24~:kB=\\E[Z:kh=\\E[1~:@1=\\E[1~:kH=\\E[4~:@7=\\E[4~:kN=\\E[6~:kP=\\E[5~:kI=\\E[2~:kD=\\E[3~:ku=\\EOA:kd=\\EOB:kr=\\EOC:kl=\\EOD:km:', 'WINDOW': '0', 'XDG_SESSION_TYPE': 'tty', 'MOTD_SHOWN': 'pam', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', 'SSH_CONNECTION': '10.0.0.12 60522 10.0.0.19 22', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'XDG_SESSION_CLASS': 'user', 'PYTHONPATH': '/mnt/NetworkShare/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib:', 'TERM': 'screen.xterm-256color', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', 'SHLVL': '2', 'XDG_SESSION_ID': '1', 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR': '/run/user/1000', 'SSH_CLIENT': '10.0.0.12 60522 22', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', 'STY': '1116.pts-0.ubuntuserver', 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS': 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus', 'BUILDDIR': '/mnt/NetworkShare/yocto/poky/build', 'SSH_TTY': '/dev/pts/0', 'OLDPWD': '/mnt/NetworkShare/yocto/poky', '_': '/mnt/NetworkShare/yocto/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake'}, ['/mnt/NetworkShare/yocto/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake', 'core-image-sato']]
1221 13:38:33.830099 Command Completed
1221 13:38:33.831731 Processing Client
1221 13:38:33.832344 Disconnecting Client
1221 13:38:33.833129 No timeout, exiting.
1221 13:38:33.933875 Exiting
1221 13:38:33.942717 Original lockfile contents: ['1221\n']
1221 13:38:33.954461 Exiting as we could obtain the lock
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/mnt/NetworkShare/yocto/poky/build/bitbake-cookerdaemon.log' mode='a+' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Comment: Your network share has some sort of I/O limitations. You can keep debugging it or you can just use local storage.

Comment: I'm running into what I think is the same problem in a slightly different variant. I'm using CROPS/poky and local mounts .. It has something to do with the way Unraid manages disk writes. I can build very well if I put `/poky` and `/poky/build` on a USB drive or a builtin drive using the unassigned devices plugin. Almost like the processes are waiting for an ACK from the filesystem that never comes. If I try to put either of those folders on the array the fetcher processes stall at 100%. Downloads and sstate is fine on the array though .. ??

Answer (score 0):

It means your hard disk is full. You should delete some files before re-running job to create a new image.